# Test standard controller - Salesforce

Tags: controller, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I am attempting to test this code. I need to set up the controller and set the parameters. 
CONTROLLER.

The visualForce page has a standard controller of contact

```
Public Class myClass{
public ApexPages.standardController controller  {get; set;}
public string pid {get; set;}

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public myClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        this.controller = controller;
        pId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
}
```

TEST CLASS

```
@isTest
public class testMyClass{

    static testMethod void myTest(){
        PageReference pageRef = Page.myPage;
    Test.setCurrentPageReference(pageRef);

        //create contact
        Contact cont = new Contact(name ='bob');
        insert cont;

        ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().put('pid', cont[0].id);
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(cont[0]);
        myClass sic = new myClass(sc);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put(?);
        System.assertEquals('something here');
    }
}
```

Comment: So...what's the question, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks you pointed me in the right direction. Ultimately, this is what worked for me,

```
Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().put('id', cont[0].id)
```

The way you suggested gives this error " System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject"

Answer (score 2):

```
    ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().put('id', cont[0].id);
    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(cont[0]);
    myClass sic = new myClass(sc);
    System.assertEquals(sic.pid,cont[0].id);
```